Raspberry Pi 5 Integrate Sensor With Linear Actuator
Raspberry Pi 5 Using GPIOZERO
I want to integrate my sensor together with my linear actuator in raspberry pi 5. So my goal here is just like the doors in supermarket, it opens automatically when someone comes to the door. When the sensor detects movement i want the linear actuator to expand and when no movement it automatically retracts.
This is my code
I Tried this code but it doesnt go the way i wanted
How can I expand the actuator when it detects motion and retracts when it doesnt detects motion?
from gpiozero import MotionSensor, OutputDevice
from signal import pause
from time import sleep

#Relay Jumper Default Value
#Channel 1 = pin(26)
#Channel 2 = pin(20)
#Channel 3 = pin(21)
sensor = MotionSensor(14)
expand_relay = OutputDevice(21, active_high=False, initial_value=False)
retract_relay = OutputDevice(20, active_high=False, initial_value=False)

def when_pressed_expand():
    expand_relay.toggle()

def when_pressed_retract():
    retract_relay.toggle()

def with_motion():
    #Expand For 5 Seconds
    expand_relay.toggle()
    sleep(5)
    retract_relay.toggle()
    
def no_motion():
    retract_relay.toggle()
    sleep(5)
    
sensor.when_motion = with_motion
sensor.when_no_motion = no_motion

pause()


What's your specific question?

i want to my code to be like the door in a supermarket that the actuator expand when it sense motion and retract if it detects no motion

That neither specific nor a question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Can you please help me on what is the correct way on triggering the actuator to expand when the sensor detects motion?
